# lotusSpellChecker and ckeditor Xpages?

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I'd like to activate the spellcheck plugin in CKEditor but it seems that IBM has disabled the native plugin.

Looking at the config.js in the data\domino\html\ckeditor directory on the Domino server I see this code describing a plugin called lotusSpellChecker but enabling this plugin doesn't seem to do anything.

```js
config.lotusSpellChecker = {
    restUrl:'',
    lang:'en',
    suggestions:'5',
    format:'json',
    highlight: { element : 'span', styles : { 'background-color' : 'yellow', 'color' : 'black' } },
    preventCache: true
};
```

Does anybody know how to activate this plugin and why the native one has been disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only successfully activated the built-in spell checker by downloading the latest CKEditor release, copying it to the server and using that on an Xpage. See my post on the XPage forum for details:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=A198C7153DBD84348525798B0056DC6B

I've tried activating it in the default CKEditor installation but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Did replacing the CKEditor version on the domino server cause any other issues? I know the version supplied with Domino has some special configuration and themes in it. did you merge with these or replace entire directory structure?

Comment: Didn't test the extended functionality or merge any functionality. Just needed the basic editor functionality so I installed it next to the existing one in a separate folder on the server./

Answer (score 1):

I can't make an official statement as to why it is disabled, but it is most likely for licensing reasons.

CKEditor uses Web Spell Checker. Details are here.

http://www.webspellchecker.net/

Answer (score 1):

The plugin can be activated by making some changes to the config.js file located in the ckeditor folder. Uncomment the folowing block:

```
//Example Lotus Spell Checker config.
/*
config.extraPlugins += ',lotusspellchecker';
config.lotusSpellChecker = {
    restUrl:'',
    lang:'en',
    suggestions:'5',
    format:'json',
    highlight: { element : 'span', styles : { 'background-color' : 'yellow', 'color' : 'black' } },
    preventCache: true
};
*/
```

Note: you need to provide the restUrl of whatever spell checking service you are going to use. Instructions here only solve the "how to activate plugin" question.

You also need to provide some Dojo properties in your rich text control:

This one adds the spell check button (LotusSpellChecker) to the toolbar.

**Property name**: toolbar

**Property value:** var myToolbar = "[['Format', 'Font','FontSize'], \n"
        +"['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','TextColor','BGColor','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','NumberedList','BulletedList'], \n"
        +"['Indent','Outdent'], \n"
        +"['Subscript','Superscript'], \n"
        +"['RemoveFormat', '-','MenuPaste','-','Undo','Redo','Find','LotusSpellChecker','-','Image','Table','Link','Flash','-','PageBreak','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar','Blockquote','Smiley','ShowBlocks'], \n"
        +"['BidiLtr','BidiRtl'], \n"
        +"['Maximize']]";
return myToolbar;

This one activates the plugin.

**Property name:** extraPlugins

**Property value:** lotusspellchecker

This is what you get:

[image: This is what you get]

Answer (score 1):

Domino 9.0.1 FP2 adds spell checker functionality through the default CKEditor toolbar and through the 'IbmSpellChecker" toolbar button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an update on this. SPR PHAN8R2GRE is created to look at including this functionality in a later release. In case you need to add a customer report to it.

All modern browsers come with spell checking capabilities which should activate for you on the field.